# getting a text value populated by a select option

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i am in dire need here. i have gone to every person i know that knows php/mysql/ajax, but no one can help.

i am trying to get an input field populated with data from my dbase that is chosen from two different selects. here is the situation:

building a golf scoring page on my website. the user will choose a course (select #1), then the tee they played (select #2), which then the disabled text inputs will populate with the rating and slope. the rating and slope are very important b/c they help figure out the handicap for the user. i am able to get everything to populate fine, but i can't figure out the correct WHERE clause in my query on the get_rating.php page. can somebody help me with that query?

here is my code:

dbase setup:

this is pulling from 2 tables, one is the courses table (course_id, c_id, name) and the other is the course_tees table (tee_id, course_name, c_id, t_id, color, rating, slope). the c_id's on both tables are the same.

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post" class='new_score'>
  <div class='form-group'>
    <select class="form-control" name="course_name" onchange="get_tees(this.value)">
      <option value="">select a tee</option>
        <?php get_courses() ?>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class='form-group'>
    <select class='form-control' name='tee_played' onchange="get_rating(this.value)" id='txtHint'>
      <option value="">select a tee</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="getRating">
  </div>
```

the first select uses the get_tees.php code (listed below) and the second one uses the get_rating.php code (listed 2 below) which is the one i'm having trouble with.

get_tees.php

```
$con = mysqli_connect("***","***","***","***") or die("connection was not established"); 

$q = intval($_GET['q']);

mysqli_select_db($con,"course_tess");
$sql="SELECT * FROM course_tees WHERE c_id = '".$q."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        $tee_id = $row['tee_id'];
        $c_id = $row['c_id'];
        $t_id = $row['t_id'];
        $tee_color = $row['color'];
        $cor_rating = $row['rating'];
        $cor_slope = $row['slope']; ?>

        <option value='<?php echo $tee_id ?>'><?php echo $tee_color ?></option>
```

get_rating.php

```
$con = mysqli_connect("***","***","***","***") or die("connection was not established"); 

$q = intval($_GET['q']);

mysqli_select_db($con,"course_tees");
$sql="SELECT * FROM course_tees";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$c_id = $row['c_id'];
$t_id = $row['t_id'];
$cor_rating = $row['rating'];
$cor_slope = $row['slope']; ?>

<input type='text' name='cor_rating' class='form-control' value='<?php echo $row['rating']; ?>' disabled>
<input type='text' name='cor_slope' class='form-control' value='<?php echo $row['slope']; ?>' disabled>
```

and here's my ajax for both selects:

```
function get_tees(str) {
if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","get_tees.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
}

function get_rating(str) {
if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("getRating").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("getRating").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","get_rating.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
}
```

am i not passing something correctly in my ajax? what am i doing wrong?!?!  PLEASE help!!

Comment: Can you simplify it a bit? Does the first AJAX fire? Does the value get returned? Does the page update correctly? Kinda hard where you are hanging up right now.. Is `mysqli_select_db($con,"course_tees");
$sql="SELECT * FROM course_tees";` the correct table and DB for ratings?

Comment: @chris85 yes everything is firing correctly, the only thing that doesn't come through correctly are the ratings and slopes ... the course name/id and the tee is coming over ... you said simplify, i am completely open to doing that ... what are you thinking might be an easier way to handle? like i said, i'm at the end of my rope with this function ... thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 0):

@chris85 this is essentially the bandaid that i have put over the issue for right now ... instead of trying to populate the text fields automatically, i am listing them in the selects and manually putting in the rating/slope ... this is my code:

php:

```
mysqli_select_db($con,"course_tess");
$sql="SELECT * FROM course_tees WHERE c_id = '".$q."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<option value=''>select a tee</option>";

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        $tee_id = $row['tee_id'];
        $c_id = $row['c_id'];
        $t_id = $row['t_id'];
        $tee_color = $row['color'];
        $cor_rating = $row['rating'];
        $cor_slope = $row['slope']; ?>

        <option value='<?php echo $tee_color ?>'><?php echo $tee_color ?> - <?php echo $cor_rating ?> : <?php echo $cor_slope ?></option>
```

and the form:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post" class='new_score'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <select class="form-control" name="course_name" onchange="get_tees(this.value)">
                        <option value="">select a tee</option>
                        <?php get_courses() ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <select class='form-control' name='tee_played' onchange="get_rating(this.value)" id='txtHint'>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cor_rating" placeholder="enter rating from above">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cor_slope" placeholder="enter slope from above">

                </div>
```

so, like you can see, it's just a bandaid. if you want to see it working, go to the http://www.havikmarketing.com and sign in with these credentials:

EM: test@test.com
PW: testing123

then go up to the settings (gears) and choose 'new round'. go through and enter a score ... you'll see how it pulls everything through. now mind you, i just have it set up as pretty much a skeleton right now ... so no judging on the design :)

thanks again